# Using the bump sdk with Corona sdk or trigger.io

Tags: android, iphone, ios, coronasdk, trigger.io

I was wondering if it was possible to use the bump sdk (http://bu.mp/company/api) with corona or trigger.io or do I have to write the app in Objective C in order to use the bump sdk

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to use the bump sdk with Trigger.io since we do not allow users to add arbitrary native plug-ins to our framework.

However, plug-ins are on our medium term roadmap and we'll post here again when our plug-in interface is ready to code to. If you want early access, email support@trigger.io